# Math: align* inside Tcolorbox

Tags: math-mode, align, tcolorbox

I'm framing certain elements in my document with the `framed` and the `empheq`- packages.

However, since i wanted a uniform way to just use one environment, i figured using `tcolorbox` would be the easiest way to go. I defined my own box as

```
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{before=\centering, hbox, drop fuzzy shadow, enhanced, colback=white, sharp corners, colframe=red, fonttitle=\bfseries, title=#1, center title}
```

However now, i can't include displayed math in a lot of environments inside that new box! In my case, i usually get away with just using the `align*` environment, but i didn't find anything on the internet, nor in the TcolorBox-Manual, that taught me how to add support for `align*` (which i think i have to).

Can someone help me out?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox, mathtools}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{before=\centering, hbox, drop fuzzy shadow, enhanced, colback=white, sharp corners, colframe=red, fonttitle=\bfseries, title=#1, center title}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}
  \begin{align*}
    z &= r \cos \varphi + \Im r \sin \varphi = r e^{\Im \varphi}\\
    r &= |z| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}
  \end{align*}
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

Error:

```
ERROR: Missing \endgroup inserted.

--- TeX said ---
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.86 \end{mybox}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox, mathtools}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{before=\centering, drop fuzzy shadow, enhanced, colback=white, sharp corners, colframe=red, fonttitle=\bfseries, title=#1, center title}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}
  \begin{align*}
    z &= r \cos \varphi + \Im r \sin \varphi = r e^{\Im \varphi}\\
    r &= |z| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}
  \end{align*}
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

You need to remove the `\hbox` as `align` is a display construct.

[image]

Or, if you want the hbox, use an inline math markup, with `aligned` rather than `align*`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox, mathtools}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{before=\centering, hbox, drop fuzzy shadow, enhanced, colback=white, sharp corners, colframe=red, fonttitle=\bfseries, title=#1, center title}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}
  $\begin{aligned}
    z &= r \cos \varphi + \Im r \sin \varphi = r e^{\Im \varphi}\\
    r &= |z| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}
  \end{aligned}$
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I added the hbox, because I want to restrict the size of the box to fit the width of whatever is inside the box. Dropping the hbox-option makes align* work, however it obtains space at the sides, as well as on top. How can i fit the width without the hbox-option?

Comment: an `align` is a display construct, it is always full width. if you want hbox you can use an inline construct such as `$\begin{aligned}` rather than `align`.  You would get exatly the same issues with a simple `\fbox`,  `\fbox{\begin{align}` does not work, `\fbox{$\begin{aligned}` does. @TimHilt

Comment: Can you maybe point me to some  documentation that explains the $\begin{...} syntax? So far i haven't found anything on the internet, nor in the LaTeX Companion and i don't really understand how to use this! @DavidCarlisle

Comment: @TimHilt `$` is just the basic way to enter inline math, like `$1+x^2$`  and `aligned` is described in the amsmath documentation `amsldoc.pdf` as an inline version of `align` for making a term in a math expression rather than an entire display.

Comment: @TimHilt I put both versions in the answer.

Comment: Ok, i understood! Now it does exactly what i want! Thank you!

Comment: can this be adapted to be use with `flalign` environment?